# Best way to process different POST requests in a single Class Based View?

Tags: django, django-views

Developing my first application here and im using a class based view`(django.views.generic.base.View`) to handle requests from a webpage.

On the webpage I have different forms that send out POST requests, for example, there is text posting form, comment form, vote button, etc. and Im checking `POST.has_key()` to see which form has been posted and processing according to that.

Whats a better way to do it? And is it possible to define method names such as post_text, post_comment etc and configure dispatch() to run the method accordingly?

Comment: why don't you create different endpoints (with view/method/classes) for different post actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
class AwesomeView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # This code is basically the same as in dispatch
        # only not overriding dispatch ensures the request method check stays in place.

        # Implement something here that works out the name of the 
        # method to call, without the post_ prefix
        # or returns a default method name when key is not found.
        # For example: key = self.request.POST.get('form_name', 'invalid_request')
        # In this example, I expect that value to be in the 'key' variable

        handler = getattr(
                           self,  # Lookup the function in this class
                           "post_{0}".format(key),  # Method name
                           self.post_operation_not_supported  # Error response method
                         )
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post_comment(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("OK")  # Just an example response
```

Comment: The method name gets constructed depending on the key? For ex. if key has 'comment' then post_comment will get called?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (here: "post_{0}".format(key)), and if it does not exist, post_operation_not_supported will be called.